# Can't do the QUERY PostgreSQL. If two athletes received the same number of points, give both the same place

Tags: postgresql

[TABLE][1]I'm new at this and can't do the task for my teacher in PostgreSQL. I have 4 columns, I have to give Emily and Vanessa the same place, but I don't understend how to do it

I tried to do it by using function with IF statements, tried to count by Points,but it didn't give any results.

TABLE:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VlMx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dense_rank` function should do the heavy lifting for you:

```sql
SELECT athlete, points, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS place
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Tahnk you so much